# Extract file data to 4 seperate tables

Tags: c, arrays, file

Having a file named `employes.dat` that contains data sorted as so:

```
Tremblay Alain            A 35.0 35.5
Vachon Jean               P 40.0 22.75
Lapalme Justin            O 40.0 15.75
Deschenes Sylvie          P 35.0 25.0
Lachance Carl             O 37.5 18.0
Labonte Chantal           P 40.0 20.0
Doucet Michel             A 40.0 33.75
```

I want to put the names, the letter, the number1 and number2 into 4 separate tables (`char names[]`, `char letter[]`, `float number1[]` and `float number2[]`).

I tried using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{

FILE *entree;

char nom[750], poste[30]; 
int i = 0;
float nbHeure[30], taux[30];

if(entree =fopen("employes.dat", "r")) {
    fscanf(entree, "%30c %1c %4f %5f", &nom[i], &poste[i], &nbHeure[i], &taux[i]);
    while(!feof(entree))
        fscanf(entree, "%30c %1c %4f %5f", &nom[i+1], &poste[i+1], &nbHeure[i+1], &taux[i+1]);
    fclose(entree);
}

else printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier!");

printf("%c", nom[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work... Can someone help me please? Its a homework and I'm just starting programming in C. Don't bother with the names, its french fyi.

Comment: Shouldn't you increment `i`?

Comment: im doing so when writing [i+1].

Comment: The `%c` format is for single letters. For strings, that is char arrays, use `%s`. It is good that you specify a maximum length in the formats, but the`scanf` family of functions requires this to be one less than the buffer size.

Comment: `char nom[750]` --> `char nom[30][25+1] ={{0}}`

Comment: @VendettaHazard: No. `i` will always be 0 and `i + 1` will therefore always be 1. You need `i = i + 1` or `i += 1` or `i++`.

Comment: why is stackoverflow not a good place for homework?

Comment: It's onl a bad place for homework indirectly.  Students often post cdoe with just 'it doesn't work' or the like, ie. without explaining what happened that should not have happened, what did not happen that should have happened, what error messages were generated, what log entries were generated, what inputs were provided, what outputs were generated, what was found during their own debugging efforts.  Such questions, with their implication that SO contributors should all go over the same ground as the OP has already travelled, in parallel, are depressing if not actually disrespectful:(

Answer (score 1):

fix sample like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *entree;

    char nom[30][25+1] ={{0}}, poste[30];
    float nbHeure[30], taux[30];
    int i = 0;

    if(entree = fopen("employes.dat", "r")) {
        while(i < 30 && 4==fscanf(entree, " %25c %c %f %f", nom[i], &poste[i], &nbHeure[i], &taux[i])){
            ++i;
        }
        fclose(entree);

        int n = i;
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            printf("%s, %c, %.1f, %.2f\n", nom[i], poste[i], nbHeure[i], taux[i]);
    }
    else
        printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier!");

    return 0;
}
```

---

end trim version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *trimEnd(char *str){
    if(!str || !*str)
        return str;
    char *endp = strchr(str, '\0');
    while(isspace(*--endp)){
        *endp = 0;
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *entree;

    char nom[30][25+1] ={{0}}, poste[30];
    float nbHeure[30], taux[30];
    int i = 0;

    if(entree = fopen("employes.dat", "r")) {
        while(i < 30 && 4==fscanf(entree, " %25c %c %f %f", nom[i], &poste[i], &nbHeure[i], &taux[i])){
            ++i;
        }
        fclose(entree);

        int n = i;
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            printf("%s, %c, %.1f, %.2f\n", trimEnd(nom[i]), poste[i], nbHeure[i], taux[i]);
    }
    else
        printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bluepixy

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code with minimal changes, so you won't lose your initial idea, and I will explain what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

FILE *entree;

char nom[750], poste[30]; 
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
float nbHeure[30], taux[30];

if(entree =fopen("employes.dat", "r")) {
    fscanf(entree, "%25c %1c %4f %5f", &nom[j], &poste[i], &nbHeure[i], &taux[i]);
    while(!feof(entree)) {

        j = j + 25;
        i = i + 1;
        fscanf(entree, "%25c %1c %4f %5f", &nom[j], &poste[i], &nbHeure[i], &taux[i]);

        if (!feof(entree)) {

        } else {
            j = j - 25;
            i = i - 1;
        }

    }
    fclose(entree);
}

else printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier!");

    printf ("%s \n \n", nom);
    printf ("%s \n \n", poste);

    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        printf ("%f ", nbHeure[k]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        printf ("%f ", taux[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have declared another integer , j

```
int j = 0;
```

Because the i integer will point to the position inside your arrays in which one element has the size of 1, and the j integer will point to the position inside the array in which every element has the size of more than one (in our case, I counted, it's 25 per name). Let me explain by example:

If j is now 0, the next name we write in the nom array will be starting from position 0. Correct.

```
j = 0; fscanf(... %25c ... &nom[j]...);
```

Which means all characters from position j=0 to position j=24 (= 25 characters in total) will be filled with the first name from your file. Good

The next name we want to write should start from the ending position of the previous name. Which is 25 exactly. To do this we increase j value by 25 
    j = j + 25;
Now the next word will be written starting from j+25 to j+49 . And so on.

One more thing you will notice I did was to add this :

```
if (!feof(entree)) {

    } else {
        j = j - 25;
        i = i - 1;
    }
```

When reading from a file, you are asking at the top **Is the file over yet?** (feof). If not, continue reading. But the file is not over until you read a special EOF character from the file. When you read it you also try to write the name and tax and poste also, which is not what we want. The if else I wrote simply avoids reading the last line from the file, which resembles the EOF I told you about.

Lastly, I added some printing for your arrays so you can see the results.

Hope this helped.